# How to safely convert strings to date?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using the DATE function to get the date from three variables for year, month and date, like this:

`DATE(year_var, month_var, day_var) AS date_ymd`

However, occasionally this would result in an invalid date, e.g., month_var may be 11 and day_var 31. In these cases DATE would fail, as 2022-11-31 is not a valid date.

Instead, I would need to have NULL as the result .

I'm looking for something like [SAFE_CAST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#safe_casting), but for dates.

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What date would you like 2022-11-31 to be?

Comment: As it's an invalid date, I would like date_ymd to be NULL.

Comment: I did not understand question. I appologize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`SAFE.` prefix](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-reference#safe_prefix) for safe function calls.

```sql
SELECT SAFE.DATE(2022, 11, 31) AS date_ymd;
```

[image]